# Zigbee communication among 3 devices is carrying garbage along with the actual data transmitted

Tags: zigbee

I am broadcasting `Hello` using one Xbee (say A).....Xbee (say B) and Xbee (say C) are receiving a lot of garbage values before and after `Hello`.

All the baudrates are 9600...where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you posted an example of the data you see, perhaps the hex values of each byte.

My guess is that you've configured the modules for "API mode" which wraps payloads with a header (starting with `0x7E`, the character `~`) and footer.  It's useful for "smart" devices because it supports multiple packet types.

Check your settings, and make sure you're using `ATAP=0`.  You can use XCTU to change the settings, or from a terminal use the escape sequence (1 second pause, `+++`, 1 second pause then module should respond with `OK`) to enter command mode.  In command mode, first set `ATAP0` and then `ATWR` to save the changes.